# WOOCOMMERCE - RETRIEVING SUBSCRIPTION VARIATION SELECTED BY CUSTOMER

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Using a woocommerce hook to retrieve the sales information after the payment has been received.  I can find the product name, the fact that it is a subscription, but I need to retrieve the subscription variation that was selected by the customer.  I can get a list OF the variations, but not the exact one selected.

Everything works EXCEPT the ability to discover what variation the customer choose,

I even tried getting the meta data, only to not be able to gain access to it.

`$meta_data = $product->get_formatted_meta_data('_', true);`

```
foreach( $items as $item_id => $product )
     {  
     $ProductName         = $product->get_name();        // readable name of 
     product
     $ProductId           = $product->get_product_id();  // woocommerce id of 
     product
     $PaymentAmount       = $product->get_total();       // Get Payment of subscription item, 
     $ProductIndex        = wc_get_product($ProductId);
     if(! WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $ProductIndex ) )  
        continue;

     if(!$product->is_type( 'simple' ))
     {
      // THIS CRASHES WITH INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR

      $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
      foreach($variation_attributes as $attribute_taxonomy => $term_slug)
        {
        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute_taxonomy );
        $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
       $BusinessSpeciality = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name;
       }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..simple:

```
foreach( $items as $item_id => $product )
{   
if(!$product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_virtual())
{
$variation_id       = $product['variation_id'];
$variation          = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$BusinessSpeciality = current($variation->get_variation_attributes());  
}
else
 $BusinessSpeciality = 'Default'; 

}`
```